# Razor Syntax with mixed markup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

MVC 5.1

I have the id of a photo in my Model. Model.PhotoId

When I try to mix it into the HTML, there is a failed error message

```
 <img src="/path/path/@Model.PhotoId.jpg"/>
```

Now do I tell Razor that the **PhotoId** has ended and the "**.jpg**" has begun?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use the `@` character with an argument as well. This is actually my preferred method when mixing razor in.

```
<img src="/path/path/@(Model.PhotoId).jpg"/>
```